# Why would this HOC class not return a rendered child component in React?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have the following code that wraps a function for providing context to child components, however, when I try to render this, it fails, my wrapped component doesn't render, in React 16.6.3

```
import React from 'react'

export const WishlistContext = React.createContext(null)


const AddToWishListButtonWrapper = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return class WishlistButton extends React.Component {
    state = {token: null, wishlistItems: []}
    render() {
      const {token, wishlistItems} = this.state
      return (
        <WishlistContext.Provider value={wishlistItems}>
          <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
        </WishlistContext.Provider>
      )
    }
  }
}

export default AddToWishListButtonWrapper
```

Then in my other component it looks like this:

```
import AddToWishListButtonWrapper from 'src/components/wishlist_button'
```

...

```
      <AddToWishListButtonWrapper>
        <WishlistButton>
          {'   '}{wishlistSuccess ? 'Added!' : 'Add to Wishlist'}
        </WishlistButton>
      </AddToWishListButtonWrapper>
```

This renders nothing, however, if I make the following change to lowercase with my import in my component and my JSX, the wrapped component renders, while none of the lifecycle methods are triggered, which is baffling.

```
import addToWishListButtonWrapper from 'src/components/wishlist_button'

          <addToWishListButtonWrapper>
            <WishlistButton>
              {'   '}{wishlistSuccess ? 'Added!' : 'Add to Wishlist'}
            </WishlistButton>
          </addToWishListButtonWrapper>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the HOC correctly. You need to create an instance of the component  like

```
import React from 'react'

export const WishlistContext = React.createContext(null)


const AddToWishListButtonWrapper = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return class WishlistButton extends React.Component {
    state = {token: null, wishlistItems: []}
    render() {
      const {token, wishlistItems} = this.state
      return (
        <WishlistContext.Provider value={wishlistItems}>
          <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
        </WishlistContext.Provider>
      )
    }
  }
}

export default AddToWishListButtonWrapper
```

---

```
const MyComp = () => (
   <WishlistButton>
        {'   '}{wishlistSuccess ? 'Added!' : 'Add to Wishlist'}
   </WishlistButton>
)
const WrapComponent = AddToWishListButtonWrapper(MyComp)
```

and render it like

```
<WrapComponent />
```

or instead of HOC you can use the `render props pattern` like

```
import React from 'react'

export const WishlistContext = React.createContext(null)


const AddToWishListButtonWrapper = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return class WishlistButton extends React.Component {
    state = {token: null, wishlistItems: []}
    render() {
      const {token, wishlistItems} = this.state
      const { children } = this.props;
      return (
        <WishlistContext.Provider value={wishlistItems}>
          {children()}
        </WishlistContext.Provider>
      )
    }
  }
}

export default AddToWishListButtonWrapper
```

---

```
<AddToWishListButtonWrapper>
     {() => (
        <WishlistButton>
          {'   '}{wishlistSuccess ? 'Added!' : 'Add to Wishlist'}
        </WishlistButton>
     )}
</AddToWishListButtonWrapper>
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. I don't know why I tried to structure it that way, the lowercase element I guess makes an empty html wrapper element, and it had me confused.

Comment: Glad to have helped (y)

Answer (score 0):

The HOC `AddToWishListButtonWrapper` is a javascript function. It expects you to call it as a function and provide a component as it's argument

You need to use it something like this (I made the case of AddToWishListButtonWrapper small as that's the convention) -

```
const EnhancedWishList = addToWishListButtonWrapper(WishlistButton)
```

And then render it like this -

```
<EnhancedWishList />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HOC as follows:

```
class WishlistButton extends Component{
  -- component logic
}

export default AddToWishListButtonWrapper(WishlistButton);
```